# Poor sound quality from laptop's built-in speakers only on Ubuntu

Tags: sound

On Ubuntu (every version I tried since about ~2009 or 2008), the sound quality is noticeably different than on Windows XP, *regardless* of what program I use for playback (YouTube, listening to MP3s, Spotify, etc.)

The sound is clearly worse and less natural on Ubuntu: my laptop sounds somewhat like a tin can (for lack of a better way to describe it), and when the volume gets even moderately high, the laptop case starts to resonate (which is just awful, and never happens on Windows XP, not even at the highest volume).

*Please note*---this is not a subjective quality difference: the laptop case will resonate on Ubuntu as soon as the volume gets turned up to mid-level.  It does not on Windows even at maximum volume.

**Some extra info about my setup**

The computer is a Dell Inspiron 6000, with "SigmaTel C Major Audio" sound.  On Windows I'm using the default drivers from Dell, I didn't modify any settings, and I checked that no extra sound processing is enabled (e.g. 3D or bass boost or whatever that's available on some computers).   On Ubuntu 11.10 I'm also using the defaults.  There's no noticeable difference in the sound *volume* of Ubuntu and WinXP.

**Questions**

1. Why is there a difference in sound quality?

   Doesn't the audio data that is sent by programs get "rendered" to speakers as-is?  Is there some extra processing, perhaps to compensate for the characteristics of the speakers or laptop case, akin to colour-management?
2. What can I do to fix this, and make Ubuntu sound as natural as Windows XP on my laptop?

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious you can try disassembling the laptop enough to get the speakers loose, then fill any cracks with [Blu-tack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack) or any similar product. I do this with my mobile phone which is quite a bit easer than doing it with a lappy. Works well, though. No more resonation from the case.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather not take it apart---I am still hoping for a software based solution.  I suspected something might be wrong with the driver on Ubuntu.

Comment: For diagnostics have you tried a Live CD of Ubuntu or a different distro ie: Puppy just to "SEE" if there was truly a difference? I cannot say if resonant frequencies differ in windows 7 vs Ubuntu but I suppose anything is possible. One more thing to consider is the difference between external speakers attached? Got to think about that!

Comment: I've got good results in the past with checking that any pre-amplification is lowered, but I don't know how to do this in 11.10, it 'just works'. Maybe try installing Pavucontrol from the Software Center and see if it can reduce the [overmodulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overmodulation). Out of ideas now, good luck...

Comment: @Tom "pre-amplification" <-- what is that?  Is it a software-based (digital) amplification?  I don't think WinXP has that, so maybe it could be the source of the trouble.  I'll google for it.

Comment: @Tom Can you give a hint on where to look for this setting in pavucontrol?  I can't see any other settings than volume controls.

Comment: Pavucontrol was for finer-grained EQ control, for preamp all I can find is [this](http://exploreubuntu.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/equalizer-for-pulse-audio/) which links to a PPA with [this .deb](https://launchpad.net/~psyke83/+archive/ppa/+files/pulseaudio-equalizer_2.7_all.deb) Last update > 1 year ago for Lucid. It may still install, and definitely has a preamp control. As always, installing & using random .debs and PPAs is at your own risk, I haven't tested any of this. I'm just good at searching.

Comment: @Szabolcs any objections we do something to this question or do you think any of the answers is worthy?

Comment: @Bruno I am sorry I haven't replied yet.  I have some heavy deadlines coming up, so I just didn't manage yet.  I wanted to try installing alsa-hda-dkms first, then if it doesn't help then install OSS4, and see if it makes a difference (although I really don't think the difference is due to the mixer used---that can't have such a clearly audible difference).  I simply don't want to mess up my system before a deadline.

Comment: @Szabolcs Take your time, I will check back in 2 weeks ;)

Comment: @Bruno Thanks! I didn't forget, but I'm having a BIG exam-like-thing (to put it lightly) next week, then I'm away til apr 4, after that I'm free as a bird :) alsa-hda-dkms didn't help but want to try OSS4 too

Comment: My Dell laptops have sub-woofers that work by default in Windows but not in Ubuntu by default. This makes a **HUGE** difference in sound quality and loudness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same thing happened to me when I was using Ubuntu for the first time. The reason for me was that Ubuntu had the volume of speakers set to a too high value. Solving this problem is very easy:

- Using the sound indicator, open Sound Settings and set the sound volume slider at "unamplified", as shown in the image:

[image: sound control panel]

I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: I think you may be right about this!

Comment: @Szabolcs have you tried it did it work

Comment: Give me a bit more time.  If it turns out to be the solution, I'll accept.

Comment: This didn't help me :(

Comment: @Patryk please ask a new and put all your information about your sound settings and paste the question URL here i will be happy to help you

Comment: This is not working for me...

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the same audio discrepancy that you have.

I can't remember the name of it at the moment (haven't used Windows in a long time) but I do think there is an audio processor that enhances the audio on Windows.  I remember seeing something in the control panel about it.  Then again, maybe I'm crazy. :-P

If you don't see anything that stands out in the control panel, run `alsamixer` on Ubuntu, and check your levels that way.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment---I am certain there is no special audio processing turned on on Windows in this case.  I made sure everything is off.

Comment: thanks. changing the sound card in alsamixer fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Please check your mixer settings, I have a totally different experience, in Windows 7, my netbook sounds muted whereas in Ubuntu, it comes alive with more imaging.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what settings are you referring to?  I'd prefer to turn off *any* pre-processing of the sound data before it is output.  I believe I managed to do this in Windows XP.  How can I do this in Ubuntu as well?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing alsa-hda-dkms from the ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily repository?

Worked for me when my laptop would start distorting like a tin-can.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook Pro 9,1.
I solved the issue by going to 'System Settings'--> 'Sound'
And selecting "Speakers: Built-in Audio" in 'Play sound through' option [image: correct option --> Speakers: Built-in Audio] . Originally 'Analog output' had been selected. That instantly fixed my sound problems and gave a crisper sound.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and my headphones. Installing equalizers did not help. There simply was no bass! In my case the solution was simple:
There was a huge difference between the front and the rear audio jack of my PC!
The front jack (for headphones) was much better. 
So simply try to use the other jack?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, have you tried switching the '3D' acceleration setting of the sound card?  It might have defaulted to the 3D setting which may have boosted certain frequencies to add a to the stereo imaging of the laptop speakers.  How does it sound with headphones when you compare it in Windows?

Comment: Can you give some hints on where to find this setting?  I was unable to find it in the sound settings dialog on 11.10.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't think this setting exists, sounds like a WIndows Media Player thing.

Comment: You can install alsa mixer from the software center and access your sound card settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Open Sound System (OSSv4) with production quality enabled in the ossxmix. Unfortunately this requiers building it from source and also removing ALSA, PulseAudio from your Ubuntu and setting applications backends to OSSv4.

You should post the output of lspci -v command (run it in terminal) for audio device section. When you will know what's your soundcard then you can check if it is supported by [Open Sound System](http://manuals.opensound.com/devlists/Linux.html).

Ubuntu community documentation regarding [OpenSound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound) has commands for removing ALSA (reboot requiered) and of course installation of OSSv4 (including compiling from source). There is also the [official guide](http://www.opensound.com/wiki/index.php/Building_OSSv4_from_source) regarding that process. Before you start the compilation open up software-properties-gtk application as root and check the source code on the first tab. Then update your software sources and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep oss4-base
```

You should change configure script GRC_MAX_QUALITY=3 to GRC_MAX_QUALITY=6 that's for production quality resampler. Know you can build the .deb package.

When all that is done than it's time for [configuring applications](http://www.4front-tech.com/wiki/index.php/Configuring_Applications_for_OSSv4). You can also emulate ALSA for applications that doesn't support OSSv4 edit /etc/asound.conf or .asoundrc as per instructions on [Arch Linux OSSv4 Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Open_Sound_System).

Comment: Open Sound System is definitely superior in terms of sound quality, but unfortunately you may have problems with recording. I can't figured it out on my machine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by poor sound quality attribute to PulseAudio and ALSA? Can you backup your claims?

Comment: That's what I think when comparing PA and ALSA to OSSv4 with production quality resampler enabled. Open Sound System just sounds much, much better to me (and many others).

Comment: Thinking is not enough. You have to do an [*ABX* test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABX_test) to be taken seriously. Please revisit your answer (together with your previous answer, which you duplicate) and remove such claims as misleading. Something else is faulty in your audio pipeline and you better find what, instead accusing something you don't understand

Comment: What could cause the difference?  What I still don't understand is why the sound data output by programs isn't sent to the hardware as-is, and what sort of processing happens before it reaches the sound card.  I Googled a bit about ALSA and OSSv4 and I found that OSS4 has superior mixing.  But if only one program is outputting, then I suppose the mixer should introduce minimal to no distortions.  Regardless, I'll try to switch ALSA to OSSv4, just to see if it changes anything.  I somehow doubt that the mixer alone could have such a huge impact as what I am hearing, but ...

Comment: ... maybe the switch will fix whatever is actually causing the problem.  I have the impression that the sound I hear on Ubuntu has more high frequencies (which might cause annoying resonation), but I just don't see how this could be due to the mixer (unless ALSA is simply buggy on my hardware)

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem. Finally found a solution, it really makes the sound much better.

The problem is with default Linux config.

Add the following lines to `/etc/asound.conf` (create the file if necessary)

```
pcm.!default {
type plug
slave.pcm hw
}
```

Then copy-paste these lines to `~/.asoundrc` (create the file if necessary)

```
default-sample-format = float32ne
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 44100
default-sample-channels = 2
default-fragments = 2
default-fragment-size-msec = 125
resample-method = soxr-vhq
enable-lfe-remixing = no
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 9
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = -1
daemonize = no
```

After that you should reload your music app for changes to take effect.

Source: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-terrible-sound-in-linux-much-better-in-windows/8203/6

I removed one line from there because it caused an error for me.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem on the sound quality even on the headset. I realised it was due to default sound profile set to HSP/HFP for my headset.

I had to change it to High Fidelity Playback(A2DP Sink) which drastically changed the sound quality.

[Ubuntu Sound Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxKt.png)

Comment: The question was about built-in speakers, not wireless headphones.

Answer (score -1):

[I'm also facing the external speaker sound quality problem. To solve this problem follow simple steps.

1. connect your wireless speaker .
2. go sound setting and select your wireless speaker.
3. and also important select MODE option show in the image.
4. and select Hight Fidelity Playback(A2DP Sink)

and enjoy good quality sound ..
thanks...]

[image]