# Poor sound Quality - Looking for assistance

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The sound quality since I changed over to Ubuntu 14.04.3 is terrible but over all the past week, suing ubuntu has been awesome, only the sound quality sucks. I managed to get a semi ok sound but it is a tin sound, it is the ska preset using pulse audio equalizer. But it i not perfect by any means, I still get distortion, sometimes only ever so slight but your attention sticks, I can explain further than that. Just it is not as enjoyable as when I had XP. To ask me to delineate further is fruitless. I have tried several posts and solutions, installing all kinds of things and I just don seem to be finding the answer or though there is some improvement as mentioned already...Please assist if you know a lot about Ubuntu and sound and the two together... I tried but don even recall what exactly, various thing regarding posts about ASLA and Pavla I think it was... Any ways, I think any one is going to get the point, I need specific help here... PLEASE

Comment: Does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75395/poor-sound-quality-on-ubuntu

Comment: Ok switching from analogue helps, however, after rebooting the settings revert back to original in analogue... Any ideas? P.s. I previously went through this post but for some reason I missed the particular step or didn´t previously notice that it worked when changing from analogue.

Comment: I have started a bounty for you, the question should have a wider audience now. Once you get a working answer, just tell me and I'll give the person who answers the bounty.

Comment: please give relevant information about your Sound Card and the connected speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer).
Without any information about your current set-up(sound card,drivers,speakers etc.). The only possible solution seems to be using an equalizer that can tweak the sound a per your requirements.

Comment: Giving you the bounty just coz you tried to help. No need for it to disappear.

Comment: Sure. And a +1.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: The question wasn't mine. I was just giving a bounty to give the question a wider audience to help the OP (Original Poster).