# Horrible sound quality in Ubuntu 19.04 vs Windows 10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, quality

the quality is much worst then it was while using windows 10. 
I tried downloading pulseaudio eq using `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer` but then gave me an error while trying to open it,

`There was an error connecting to pulseaudio,
please make sure you have the pulseaudio dbus module loaded, exiting...`.

so I did a little research and edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` by adding "

```
load-module module-equalizer-sink 
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

" to it.

then I did a `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D` 
and it gave me back `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.`.

Im really new to Ubuntu so this is as far as i can go without giving up :(, i wanna have decent laptop sound like i did on windows 10.

My laptop model : hp 15-ba011ng /
DTS Studio Sound™

Comment: Get a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/75395/poor-sound-quality-from-laptops-built-in-speakers-only-on-ubuntu